# Is it possible to create a custom dictionary for Google App Script to spell check entries made by a user? Maybe an array?

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have a sheet that I'm really proud of writing my first script for.  So for a little background I work for a doctor office with well over 100 doctors.  We have about 10 people manually adding entries for new patients in our department.  So as a result, we have a ton of spelling errors for the doctor names.

What I'm really trying to do is create an array, or anything similar, with a list of all the doctors names.  I would ultimately love to have it maybe change the cell color when it detects a misspell or even just do something to catch the attention of the user.  I have a script which imports all the doctors on every tab to a "Counting" tab where we tally all the new patients by each doctor.

I tried to research this topic a bit and came up with nothing.  If this is possible I would be forever grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use validation? [Class DataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)

Comment: Oh! Thank you! That's great.  I will give this a shot!